# mAP@.50 evaluation is very poor but the identification is working well

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorboard, pre-trained-model

I'm using a pretrained model from the tensorflow2 reporsitory, the ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8, for image recognition porpuses. The training of the model went ok, however when evaluating with tensorboard with Pascal VOC Detection Metrics the Average Precision of each object is really low.

[mAP@.50 of ONE of the objects here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAyo.png)

However, when I go to the Images tab, where it shows the eval side by side images, it shows that the model is perfmorming pretty well. I fed it 8 test images  do the evaluation:

[Some images with prediction (left) and ground truth (right))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzWNY.png)

In the image it shows, in the left, the prediction of the model. and on the right the ground truth It predicted the right class with a 100% certainty. This behaviour is seen in all 8 images. So why is the AP of this object so low?

Comment: mAP uses the IoU metric, and your predicted boxes are considerably larger than the ground truth, which affects the IoU negatively.

Comment: But I used the IoU@.5. Seeing the images I think the overlap is over 50%. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's hard to see by eye, but I wouldn't be surprised if the IoU is around 0.4. Compute the IoU, you'll know.